# Can't download High Sierra from the Mac App Store

Tags: install, mac-appstore, high-sierra

When I click "Download" in the High Sierra page in Mac App Store, the button turns into a gray "Downloading" button and might even show an estimated download time but after a while it turns into a gray "Download" button that isn't clickable anymore.

This happens on my 2 Mac's: a Mac Mini running Sierra and a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running High Sierra Beta (17A360a).

**Update**: I've just restarted the download and it estimates about 1 hour to download the ~5GB of the installer. If I start another simultaneous download in the network (iOS update, for example), the transfer time starts to increase and if it reaches some value over 15h the App Store quits the download. This happens even if the installer download is still active, only at a slower rate, as can be verified by looking for "OS update" in the Console app.

**Update 2**: it seems the problem I was facing with the download “fixed itself”. Since yesterday I managed 2 full downloads without any issues on my 2 Macs.

Comment: I'm stuck in the same problem. Did you resolve the question?

Comment: @Blaszard closing the App Store and restarting the download resulted in continuing the previous download, so after more than 10 iterations I got a full installer. Using that installer cause failed installations in both my Macs and a few more restores from Time Machine. Yesterday I managed to get a full download in a single “iteration” and *that download* resulted in a successful installation in the MacBook Pro with SSD (and therefore mandatory APFS). I’m now updating my Time Machine backup for the Mac Mini to try the download on it too, using another new download that finished in one iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the App Store was at a heavy load in the first days of High Sierra availability and this might have caused my download failures. Since Friday I could download High Sierra without issues on my 2 Macs and update them without any failure.

If your download is failing, I advise patience. The App Store will try to resume a download from where it stopped, but the installers I got doing this corrupted my Mac's and I had to restore from Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't  update because your system is running with a higher beta Version of OS X.
Leave Apple beta Program with the devices and wait for a greater update than the system have at the moment.

If you need help leaving the beta Program check this:
https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll

Comment: Only the MacBook Pro has a beta, and it isn't even the GM. I've already disabled downloading betas in it. The Mac Mini is still running Sierra.